# XPath expression from a website to extract price information

Tags: xpath

I am trying to extract the price of this type of website using XPath but I don't have any experience and using an addon I got this Xpath expression `//div[@class='teaser--product-prices public-product']/div[@class='ui-table' and 1]/div[@class='ui-table-cell' and 1]/div[@class='teaser--product-final-price large sell-price' and 1]` which is not working.

The website also uses dot (.) as a thousand separator and doesn't use a dot (.) for decimals so I would really appreciate if there was a way to remove the first dot and add one for decimals through the Xpath expression.

The expression is to be used for Content Egg Wordpress plugin to feed price information to a website.

The website is https://www.public-cyprus.com.cy/product/tileoraseis/tileoraseis/tileorasi-samsung-65-smart-8k-qled-qe65q950t/prod10634476pp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following XPath expression :

```
concat(translate(//div[@class="product-main-container product-page"]/@data-price,".",""),".",translate(//div[@class="product-main-container product-page"]/@data-decimals,"€",""))
```

We use function `concat` to join the result of 2 XPath expressions. The first in which we remove the dot with funtion `translate`. The second in which we remove the euro symbol with `translate` too. We also add the decimal separator during the `concat` step.

Output :

```
6599.00
```

**Side note** : It could not work since I don't know if your plugin supports these XPath functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately, the expression doesn't work so I am gonna try asking the developers of the plugin for an explanation.